# Whats the difference between Facebook Feed Dialog and (Sharer)

Tags: facebook

I'm using a plugin called FooBox for wordpress that puts share buttons on top of images within a Pop-Over.

Within the settings of this plugin is an option to:

> Enable Facebook's new feed dialog way of sharing, rather than their old (and deprecated!) sharer.
>   Please note that this method requires a Facebook App Id in order to function!

I'm not exactly a developer... so I cannot determine what this means, if its better, how so..

Could someone explain in laymen terms what this is?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

The old sharer method is no longer deprecated, as Facebook have recently updated it (and removed the deprecated notice that was on their site for ages). Both methods have pros and cons. This is my understanding:

**FaceBook Sharer**

- Easy to implement and no facebook app id needed in order to setup
- Can share to personal timeline as well as other facebook pages you are admin for
- Sharer recently was updated (Feb/Mar 2014) and no longer accepts custom images and overrides anything you pass it with the image opengraph tags used on the page you are linking to. This is a major problem when used with lightbox solutions like FooBox, because the specific image that is shared no longer gets recognized by facebook.

**Feed Dialog**

- More involved to setup and get working. An app ID is required and the app ID cannot be shared across domains.
- It only allows you to share to your personal timeline. No support for sharing to pages that you are an admin for.
- It accepts custom images, so FooBox works and the specific image that is shared is the image that is shown in the user's timeline.

I am the developer of FooBox and will be updating the plugin soon with an updated explanation to help users on learning what the difference is.

And since Facebook have removed support for custom images since Mar 2014, we will no longer recommend the sharer, but rather push the feed dialog.

**More Info**

[Facebook documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button) on the sharer. (further down the page under the FAQ section and hardly mentioned)

[Facebook documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog) on the feed dialog.

[Response from facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/357750474364812/?comment_id=308955395926697) about no longer supporting the custom image for the sharer.

Comment: What does `FAW` mean?

Comment: FAW was meant to say FAQ - this has been corrected in my answer, but looking again at the documentation, the FAQ section has been moved to it's [own page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs)