# facebook-jssdk: Why is my feed share not overriding my og:* meta tags

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I wish to have a single-page that has runtime-generated images on it, such that the user can share them. In other words: the images are created by the users, and they need to be share-able.

My understanding (see [SO answer by @vinnie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449634/whats-the-difference-between-facebook-feed-dialog-and-sharer)) is that if you want to have a site where users can share different items with different images and content *from the same page*, that dialog/feed is the way to do it ... that dialog/feed will override og:* meta tags.

I have a simple test 'site' up that employs two sets of facebook share info. When I use the 'feed button', the og:* data is still displayed:

```
- og:* tags
- dialog/feed url

// 1 - og:* tags ... for basic page-share
<meta property="og:type"        content="website"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id"      content="#"/>    
<meta property="og:url"         content="http://toddandd.ipower.com/test__social_sharing/"/>
<meta property="og:image"       content="http://toddandd.ipower.com/test__social_sharing/images/FB_THUMB_01_1200x628.jpg"/>    
<meta property="og:title"       content="og-title:The Rock"/>
<meta property="og:site_name"   content="og-site_name:The Test Site"/>    
<meta property="og:description" content="og-description:checking how it works"/>    

// 2 - feed dialog ... for image-specific sharing (I have cleaned the href up for readability)
<a href = 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed
            ?app_id       = #
            &link         = http://toddandd.ipower.com/test__social_sharing/
            &picture      = http://toddandd.ipower.com/test__social_sharing/images/FB_THUMB_02_1200x628.jpg
            &name         = feed-title:The Rock
            &caption      = feed-site_name:The Test Site
            &description  = feed-description:checking how it works
            &redirect_uri = http://toddandd.ipower.com/test__social_sharing/'> 
  feed button
</a>
```

You can see the test here: http://toddandd.ipower.com/test__social_sharing/. *(I am not creating a plnkr or fiddle because facebook prevents cross-domain efforts.)*

Comment: Your test is not really working; your app is still in development mode, so the feed dialog gives an error (for us, not for you, because you are the app developer.)

Comment: Trying to specify those values at runtime seems to become more and more unreliable; there’s been lots and lots of reports of that recently. The only reliable way to get this to work is to provide individual URLs for the individual items you want to share, that carry the relevant meta information. (If you don’t want users who follow those links from Facebook to land on such a page, then you can redirect them to another URL – client-side via JS, or server-side with an exception for the FB scraper.)

Comment: CBroe, thanks for responding ... I failed to mention in post that what happens when I attempt the feed is *not* an error, but rather that the meta data is displayed instead (I will edit my question to indicate that in just a minute) ... ... ... Also, how do you know that my app is in development (it's fine that you know ... I'm just wondering *how* you know) ... thanks, Shannon

Comment: I know that it displays the meta data instead – that’s what I was trying to tell you, specifying those values via the Feed dialog seems to cause lots of problems lately, in that it ignores those values for the meta tags. And I know that your app is in development mode, because the error message from Facebook said so :)

Comment: I found an error in my setup ... my image for the `og:image` tag was using  lowercase `'.jpg', but the image for the `dialog/feed' was using uppercase '.JPG' (but the url string was using lowercase) ... now it is 'working' ... but CBroe's comment has me nervous nevertheless ...

Answer (score 0):

I thought about deleting this question when I discovered the solution was simply a typo, but the script that I posted in the original question might be valuable to someone  ...

My error was that my image file was saved as a `.JPG` (uppercase), but my url string was using lowercase.

Also see: [same question with lots of other possible answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721687/feed-dialog-picture-not-showing-up/36502805#36502805)